# Angularjs ui-grid ng-repeat in cellTemplate tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to use ng-repeat in cellTemplate tooltip in following way:

```
self.gridOptions = {
   data: 'screenController.data',
   enableColumnResizing: true,
   minRowsToShow: 15,
   columnDefs : [
     { field: 'setups', displayName: 'Setups', cellTemplate: 'setupTemplate.html'}]
```

where setupTemplate.html content is:

```
<div class="grid-tooltip" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-html-unsafe="<span ng-repeat='setup in row.entity.setups'>{{setup}}<br /></span>">
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
    details
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have multiline tolltip based on content of setups field which is a list of strings. But I can not see any result in tooltip. Any help?

Comment: I created a plunker regarding this issue:http://plnkr.co/edit/NCpFAkU9cggUh6bUHnwh?p=preview